# What's the equivalent to this[x] in Dart?

Tags: dart

For instance, in Javascript I can do something like:

```
class Foo {
  x = 'baz';

  bar() {
    const someVar = 'x';
    console.log(this[someVar]);
    // Output: 'baz';
  }
}
```

Hopefully that's relatively clear - it boils down to accessing a member variable by another variable's contents. How is this achieved in Dart?

Answer (score 0):

This is not trivial in Dart. Dart doesn't have a syntax to access class properties with `[]`.

There are a couple of approaches though:

**Mirrors:**

https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.1/dart-mirrors/dart-mirrors-library.html

Basically you have access to everything and offers the biggest freedom. You can check what properties a class has, access them via names and so on. Big disadvantage is that the generated JS (if targeting web) will be huge. Flutter doesn't support it at all.

**Reflectable**

To deal with the large generated JS, you can use [package:reflectable](https://pub.dev/packages/reflectable). Never tried it with Flutter. It's a bit more to set up and start using bit it works.

**Dart only solution 1**

You can overload `[]` operator on a class:

```dart
class Foo { 
  final _backing = <String, String>{
    'foo': 'bar'
  };

  operator [](String val) {
    return _backing[val];
  }
}

void main() {
  final inst = Foo();
  print(inst['foo']);
}
```

**Dart only solution 2**

Just use a map :) Well sort of... If you are dealing with complex types and you want to add some extra functionality to your map, you can do something like this:

```dart
import 'dart:collection';

class StringMap extends Object with MapMixin<String, String> {
  final _backing = <String, String>{};

  @override
  String operator [](Object key) {
    return _backing[key];
  }

  @override
  void operator []=(String key, String value) {
    _backing[key] = value;
  }

  @override
  void clear() {
    _backing.clear();
  }

  @override
  Iterable<String> get keys => _backing.keys;

  @override
  String remove(Object key) {
    return _backing.remove(key);
  }
}
```